# Trying to sort integers in a list from user input

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to write some code that will allow the user to enter many numbers, then put them into a list and then sort them ascend and then later descend.

Here is my Java code:

```
public static void questionThree() throws java.lang.Exception {
    int input1;
    int input2;
    int input3;
    int noAmount;

    List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of numbers: ");

    noAmount = user_input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < noAmount; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        input2 = user_input.nextInt();
        numberList.add(input2);
    }

    Arrays.sort(numberList);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(numberList.get(i));
    }
}
```

The console is complaining I can't use sort here.

How do you sort integers that you have just put into a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Arrays.sort(numberList);
```

That sort function takes array as a input not collection. You are using `Arrays` class which used to sort Arrays not `Collections`.

You should use

```
Collections.sort(numbersList);
```

Since you want to sort the list in reverse order

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: thanks  dude. also how would you make it descending?

Comment: @ObeseOctopus Glad to help. Updated my post

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) instead of [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) since you are sorting a Collection and not an array:

```
Collections.sort(numberList);
```

Others comments regarding your code:

- You should respect the Java naming conventions: `user_input` should be renamed to `userInput`.
- You are declaring unused variables: `input1` and `input3`.
- You should try to minimize the scope of each variable. Since `input2` is only needed inside the loop, you can write `int input2 = userInput.nextInt();` and remove its declaration at the beginning of the method.

Comment: thanks for the advice, have updated my code accordingly and up voted your answer